# Same random numbers from instantiated class

Tags: c#, random

I'm learning C# and created a class within my program that holds a random number generator:

```
class RandomNumberGenerator
{
    Random RNG = new Random();
    // A bunch of methods that use random numbers are in here
}
```

Inside this class are a few methods that use the RNG.  Data gets sent here from other parts of the program, gets processed, then gets returned.  One of the methods does the following:

```
// Method works something like this
int Value1 = RNG.Next(x, y);
int Value2 = RNG.Next(x, y);
int Value3 = RNG.Next(x, y);
```

The `x`, `y` values are to be sent here from another class. So, I have to create an instance of the `RandomNumberGenerator` within that class so I can call its methods and pass the x and y values to it.

```
class DoStuff
{
    RandomNumberGenerator Randomizer = new RandomNumberGenerator
    // Here I call a bunch of Randomizer methods that give me values I need
}
```

The problem in the above method is that I get the same numbers every time for all three values. I'm not sure if it's because they're so close together and `Randomizer`'s seed value hasn't had time to change or if I'm doing something wrong when I create a new instance of the `RandomNumberGenerator` class.

I've gone through a bunch of answers on here already and typically problems like this are due to people creating many new `Random` objects when they run methods (thus setting the seed for all of them to the same value), but the only new `Random` object I create is within the `RandomNumberGenerator` class.  I then instantiate that once within the other class so I can pass it data and use its methods.

Why is this happening and how would I fix this?

Comment: Assuming you aren't creating more an one instance of your randomizer class, as the answers below are suggesting, can you post a [complete, small example](http://sscce.org/) that illustrates the problem? Something we can copy and paste into Visual Studio without having to guess at critical code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you should have one static instance of `Random`, and use that single instance to get all random numbers for your application. Make sure to `lock` if you are going to use it from multiple threads.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that is creating instances of `DoStuff` in a loop.

When invoked too quickly, multiple random instances will produce identical seeds which causes same numbers.

Declare it once outside the for loop or pass it to the method.

```
    Random r = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        // use the same random instance
    }
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The random number generation starts from a seed value. **If the same
>   seed is used repeatedly, the same series of numbers is generated**. One
>   way to produce different sequences is to make the seed value
>   time-dependent, thereby producing a different series with each new
>   instance of Random. By default, the parameterless constructor of the
>   Random class uses the system clock to generate its seed value, while
>   its parameterized constructor can take an Int32 value based on the
>   number of ticks in the current time. However, because the clock has
>   finite resolution, using the parameterless constructor to create
>   different Random objects in close succession creates random number
>   generators that produce identical sequences of random numbers.

Comment: When I created the new Random object I made sure to place it at the top of the RandomNumberGenerator class, before I started creating any methods.  All of the methods reference that single Random object and it isn't within any loops.  I didn't define any parameters when I created the object so it's using the system clock.  This is why I had a suspicion that the problem was due to the proximity of the calls, especially since every other random method in the program works as intended.